# How to install ceiling fan/light wall switch from a light switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

I bought a Parrot Uncle retractable ceiling fan/light #F3504A.

The wall switch indicates connecting the Fan, Light, and AC120V 60HZ wires all to the hot wire(black).

Problem: Now I have a white wire from the wall and no other wires to connect from the switch.

By the way, on connecting my ceiling fan the black(fan) and blue(light) wires are connected to the black wire from ceiling. The white wire is neutral.

Is there another way to connect the switch?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: How could your switch only have one wire? Are you replacing an existing switch? If so, what was the original configuration of the existing switch? Is this a special switch provided with the fan?